# Convert between nullable int and int

Tags: c#, int, nullable, enumeration

I would like to do something like this :

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int)lc.Value : null;
```

where lc is a nullable enumeration type, say EMyEnumeration?. So I want to test if lc has a value, so if then give its int value to l, otherwise l is null. But when I do this, C# complains that 'Error type of conditional expression cannot be determined as there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and ''.

How can I make it correct? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to cast `null` as well:

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int)lc.Value : (int?)null;
```

By the way, that's one of the differences between the [conditional  operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) and an `if-else`:

```
if (lc.HasValue)
    l = (int)lc.Value;
else
    l = null;  // works
```

The relevant C# specification is **7.14 Conditional operator**:

The second and third operands, x and y, of the `?: operator` control the type of the conditional expression.

- If x has type X and y has type Y then

  - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
  - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
  - Otherwise, **no expression type can be determined**, and a compile-time error occurs.

Since `int` is not convertible to `null` implicitly and vice-versa you get a compiler error. But you could also cast the `enum` to `int?` instead of `int` which *is* convertible. Then the compiler can derive the type and it'll compile:

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int?)lc.Value : null; // works also
```

or, as Sergey has mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041636/284240), directly:

```
int? l = (int?)lc;
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply cast your nullable enum value to nullable integer:

```
int? l = (int?)lc;
```

Due to C# specification 6.2.3 Explicit nullable conversions:

> Evaluation of a nullable conversion based on an underlying conversion
>   from S to T proceeds as follows if the nullable conversion is from S? to T?:
>
> - If the source value is null (HasValue property is false), the result is the null value of type T?.
> - Otherwise, the conversion is evaluated as an unwrapping from S? to S, followed by the underlying conversion from S to T, followed by a
>     wrapping from T to T?.

Comment: I was just thinking this myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should this:

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int)lc.Value : (int?)null;
```

Comment: It's not me, but I think someone spotted that you're a serial low-quality poster. If it's about malicious serial downvotes: these will be detected and undone. Preventing other downvotes is your job.