# differences between the conditional operator and an if-else:

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041519/convert-between-nullable-int-and-int#21041550) and I found [Tim Schmelter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041550/96780):

> By the way, that's one of the differences between the conditional operator and an if-else

you can check the answer for this question, and I can't found the reason ?

if conditional operator work like if-else why if else don't need the cast

**question :**

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int)lc.Value : null;
```

**"Tim Schmelter" answer :**

You have to cast `null` as well:

```
int? l = lc.HasValue ? (int)lc.Value : (int?)null;
```

By the way, that's one of the differences between the [conditional  operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041519/convert-between-nullable-int-and-int#21041550) and an `if-else`:

```
if (lc.HasValue)
    l = (int)lc.Value;
else
    l = null;  // works
```

Comment: @Akrem It clearly illustrates that you doesnt need to cast NULL in if-else , but it has to be done in Conditional operator

Comment: I believe it would be much clearer if you added here some parts of the original question/answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal `null` alone does not have a type, but it is implicitly convertible to any reference type and to any `Nullable<>` type. In the expression:

```
x = null
```

where `x` is assigned to null, the compiler can easily infer from the type of the variable (or field or property or parameter or whatever) `x` what the `null` literal shall be converted into. For example if `x` is of type `string`, the `null` shall represent the `null` reference, while if `x` is of type `int?`, the `null` shall represent an instance of `Nullable<int>` where `HasValue` is false.

If `x` is of type `int`, no implicit conversion exists, and the above expression shall not compile.

(The declaration `var x = null;` with `var` is not legal since `null` has no type in itself.)

On the other hand, in the expression:

```
someBoolean ? 42 : null /* illegal */
```

the compiler cannot figure out what type to convert `null` into. Remember that `int` is neither reference type, nor `Nullable<>` type.

If you meant **wrapping** into a nullable, use:

```
someBoolean ? (int?)42 : null
```

or:

```
someBoolean ? 42 : (int?)null
```

In both cases the compiler will automatically see that the other operand (on the other side of the colon `:`) must also be implicitly converted to `int?`.

If you meant **boxing** into some base class or interface of `int`, write that:

```
someBoolean ? (object)42 : null
```

or:

```
someBoolean ? 42 : (object)null
```

---

Now, the expressions above could be sub-expressions of a greater containing expression, but the compiler will still need the type of the `?:` expression to be clear by itself. For example in:

```
int? x;
x = someBoolean ? 42 : null; // still illegal!
```

even if the sub-expression `someBoolean ? 42 : null` appears inside a larger expression `x = someBoolean ? 42 : null` where `x` does have a type, the sub-expression must still acquire its type "intrinsically". The type of `x` cannot "leak onto" the sub-expression. This "grammar" seems to be a surprise to many new C# developers. Questions like yours are often seen, see e.g. [Nullable type issue with `?:` Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/) and the threads linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement doesn't yield a value, so the statements in the "then" and "else" parts don't need to be type compatible in any way.

The conditional operator yields a value, and therefore both parts must be type compatible in some way in order for the compiler to determine the type of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) says for the conditional operator :

*Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.*

This is the reason. In the **if-else** constructor the code in **else** block is independent from the code in **if** block so the type-casting can be inferred by the compiler in each case.

Comment: The problem with the specification is that it doesn't consider the type of the assignment. We don't have to assign the result to anything, but that is not the typical use case. The type doesn't matter when you don't assign the result, anyway. In the typical use case, I would argue that we don't really care if the expressions are compatible with each other. Only one of them will be evaluated, and the only compatible type of interest is the type of the assignment. So `int? x = b ? 42 : null` should be perfectly legal. So should `object x = b ? 42 : null`.